# How to limit user to upload videos that were taken today?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the ImagePicker package to allow users to upload videos from their device to a Flutter application. I need to be able to limit them to only be able to upload videos that were taken on the current date. Is there a parameter for this? Or is the date accessible in the metadata of the file that I can check somehow?

```
final XFile? file = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final XFile? file = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Here you get the chosen file.

Then you can try out the https://pub.dev/packages/native_exif package:

```
final exif = await Exif.fromPath(file!.path);

final originalDate = await exif.getOriginalDate();
```

Then just check in an if statement if it was taken today.

Comment: I'm getting 'null' when I print the originalDate to the console in using this on videos. Also getting null for the attributes when I use that method. Any idea why that might be?